# S3 JS SDK copyObject 403 Forbidden

Tags: javascript, aws-sdk, aws-cli

putObject works just fine:

```js
var destBucket = 'DESTBUCKETNAME';
var params = {
     Body: '01110100 01100101 01110011 01110100 01100110 01101001 01101100 01100101 01101000 01100101 01110010 01100101 ',
     Bucket: destBucket, 
     Key: "tester.mp4"
};

s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
     if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
     else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

This uploads the file and returns a successful response.

However copyObject returns a 403 forbidden on the destination object location:

```js
var sourceObject = 'testsrcfile.mp4';
var srcBucket = 'BUCKETNAME';
var destBucket = 'DESTBUCKETNAME';
var paramsCopy = {
     Bucket: destBucket,
     CopySource: srcBucket + '/' + sourceObject,
     Key: destBucket + '/' + 'testy.mp4' 
};
s3.copyObject(params, function(err, data) {
     if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
     else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Error:

```
PUT https://DESTBUCKETNAME.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/DESTBUCKETNAME/testy.mp4 403 (Forbidden)
```

Here's my CORS Config for the destination bucket:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I don't understand why putObject works while copyObject does not. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are specifying the `Key` incorrectly. Do not specify the bucket name in the Key. That is what `Bucket` is for.

```
var paramsCopy = {
     Bucket: destBucket,
     CopySource: srcBucket + '/' + sourceObject,
     Key: 'testy.mp4' 
};
```